# Finding the low and high value inside from an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, interpolation

I am wondering what the best way is to go about this problem. I'm trying to make an interpolation formula from excel into PHP. Excel formula is pretty much this:

(Value 400k - Value 350k)/((400k - 350k)/1000)*((360k coverage - Value 350k)/1000) All of that plus (Value 350k)

Right now I have coverages set up in an array like so:

```
$keyFactorArray = array(
    "75000" => "0.923",
    "80000" => "0.938",
    "85000" => "0.954",
    "90000" => "0.969",
    "95000" => "0.984",
    "100000" => "1",
    "110000" => "1.03",
    "120000" => "1.061",
    "130000" => "1.092",
    "140000" => "1.122",
    "150000" => "1.153",
    "160000" => "1.208",
    "170000" => "1.261",
    "180000" => "1.315",
    "190000" => "1.369",
    "200000" => "1.422",
    "250000" => "1.692",
    "300000" => "1.961",
    "350000" => "2.23",
    "400000" => "2.499",
    "450000" => "2.769",
    "500000" => "3.038",
    "550000" => "3.307",
    "600000" => "3.577",
    "650000" => "3.846",
    "700000" => "4.115",
    "750000" => "4.385",
    "800000" => "4.654",
    "850000" => "4.923",
    "900000" => "5.193",
    "950000" => "5.462",
    "1000000" => "5.731"
  );
```

So my coverage can be any value like 350k, or 240k etc. How do I find the index value that is above and below. I am not too sure if I am even going about this problem in the most efficient way, just going on my current knowledge of what is in front of me and what has been "shown" in the past with other code. In a nutshell the calculation would end up looking something like:

( (2.499 - 2.23)/((2.499-2.23)/1000)*((360000 - 350000)/1000) )All + 2.23

I hope someone can point me in the right direction if using an array would be the most effective way of doing this calculation or should I just put this into a table and use SQL instead possibly(Not the best at that either...)?

Comment: SQL is overkill for so few values. As long as your array is sorted in ascending order like this, just loop through the array and stop as soon as you hit a value greater than your target. That's your "above" key and then that index minus 1 is your "below" key.

Comment: Just access the array values using those keys and do the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Alex Howansky and pointing me in the right direction! Here's my code to help me do the math problem with the array:

```
foreach($keyFactorArray as $key => $value) {
  if($covA < $key) {
    $lowLimitKey = $prevKey;
    $lowLimitValue = $prevValueFactor;
    $highLimitKey = $key;
    $highLimitValue = $value;
    break;
  }
  $prevKey = $key;
  $prevValueFactor = $value;
};
$aopKeyFactor = ((($highLimitValue - $lowLimitValue) / (($highLimitKey - $lowLimitKey)/1000) * (($covA - $lowLimitKey)/1000))) + $lowLimitValue;
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do it, but this is the way that makes the most sense to me and it works!